# Use jQuery to style dynamically loaded elements

Tags: jquery, css

My page uses Ajax to populate a combo box with options from a database. Every time the options change, the width of the combo box also changes to match that of the longest option. This is annoying from a presentation standpoint, so I wanted to do the following:

First I used jQuery to find the width of the combo box in question, at the time of the page load:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var box_width = $('select#imgClass').width();           
});
```

But then I'm stuck. I tried to use `$('select#imgClass').css('width', box_width);` to set the width, but that only sets the width of the *current* iteration of the combo box, not any future versions. I thought about using `.live()`, but since that requires an event handler, it won't work either.

My last resort is to use `.append()` to create a CSS rule in the head of the page, but I wanted to ask all of you if there is a better way of doing this that I am not aware of?

Thank you.

Comment: Just use regular CSS, then it'll apply to everything regardless of when it's added to the DOM.

Comment: @David Thomas - That's what I would like to do, except that because the value I wish to use in the css is variable, it needs to be added after the page load.

Comment: @stefmikhail, I accidentally originally used `$.onReady` rather than `.ready`. I have updated my answer :)

Comment: @Ryan - Ha, I thought something was a little wonky with that... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the width of the component when the DOM becomes ready. Then you can use that to update the combo box, irrespective of what happens to it dynamically:

```
    $.ready(function() {

        // set up closure scope
        var fixedWidth = $('select#imgClass').width();

        // set up 'change' event handler to update the width using fixed width
        $('select#imgClass').live('change', function () {
            $(this).width(fixedWidth);
        ));

    });
```

UPDATE

You mentioned that you are making an AJAX call in response the `change` event of the combo box, which will cause issues with my original solution. However, you can put an object in the global space, to be a good web citizen, that can have your 'fixed' geometry values. Then your ajax call can access this value, as shown below:

```
    $.ready(function() {

        // set up global object to hold your fixed geometries
        MyGeometryValues = {};
        MyGeometryValues.imgClassSelect = $('select#imgClass').width();

    });

    $.get('/path/to/my/url', function(data) {  // success handler of AJAX call

        // do all of your other processing first

        // then, do this last
        $('select#imgClass').width(MyGeometryValues.imgClassSelect);

    )};
```

Comment: Alas, it doesn't seem to be working. It's probably because I have the ajax call being triggered on `change` as well.

Comment: @stefmikhail, no problem. Just move the logic into the success handler of your AJAX call, and add a global object that has your fixed geometry values. I have updated my answer to reflect this (in the 'UPDATE' section) :)

Comment: I see where you're going with your amended answer, and I think it would be an excellent solution if I needed to set an attribute or something other than a css value. I'm just thinking that with the my answer, there will be less for the javascript, and thus the ajax, to perform on every refresh. You see where I'm going?

Comment: @stefmikhail, if you read the [api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/), jQuery's `width` function does set the css width value.

Answer (score 0):

i think the only way is after each change of html run function that will iterate through all elements and set css.
somtething like:

```
function SetWidth(value) {
   $('.elements input').each({
   $(this).width(value);
});
}
```

Comment: This may indeed work, but I'm wondering if it wouldn't just be easier to use `.append()` to add a css rule to the end of the `head`?

Comment: i think easier would be to set classes like: .w100, .w150, .w200 and switch classes to change width.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the widths in question. I suppose to could update a css class with the largest width value whenever the database options are changed, but I wanted to come up with a code that would do that for me; Check the width on page load, and then set that width for any future iterations due to the ajax refresh. I will post my final code in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

While Taras Neporozhniy's answer below may indeed work, I feel the following will be simpler in the end, and allow for less code for every Ajax request.

The following code is for three combo boxes, while the original question only referred to one combo box for simplicity. I used concatenation to make the code more readable. Oh, and while I'm not sure exactly why, the following only works contained within `$(window).load()`. `$(document).ready()` did not work, and I suspect this is because the combo boxes are loaded via ajax.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var family_width = $('select#imgFamily').width(),
        class_width = $('select#imgClass').width(),
        gender_width = $('select#imgGender').width();   
    $('head').append('<style type="text/css">'+
                        ' select#imgFamily {width: '+ family_width +'px}'+
                        ' select#imgClass {width: '+ class_width +'px}'+
                        ' select#imgGender {width: '+ gender_width +'px}'+
                        '</style>');
});
```

Thanks to those who tried to help.

Answer (score -1):

Please read [Launching Code on Document Ready](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready) .

```
$(window).load(....);
```

Does something completely different that you think it does.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I'm curious what you think I think it does? The link you gave me is for the shorthand ajax method. When used in the method shown above, it is used to bind an event to the window load. Here's the link http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Oh, I read Ajax and just assumed that's the function you were thinking of, my bad.